# How do I update UNIQUE values in my case using sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "{subject}" (
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          text TEXT,
          fileid TEXT,
          date TEXT,
          author TEXT);
```

I want to set increase all `id` values by one:

```
UPDATE "{subject}" SET id = id + 1
```

and this gives me `UNIQUE constraint failed` error.

What should I do if I need to keep uniqueness while increasing values this way?

Update:
I want it basically like this:

```
-1, 0, 1
update()
0, 1, 2
```

Maybe I should copy the table without UNIQUE constraint, update values, then copy it back?

Comment: as id is the primary key and can be defined as id integer  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, it will auto increment. so your insert statement will be just like insert into subject(text,fileid,author) values(?,?,?), and your id will automatically increase.

Comment: @simpleApp
I want to update those values whenever I need like this:
-1, 0, 1
update()
0, 1, 2

Comment: okay, as you have set that a primary key it will bring its own constraints(uniqueness) too. if you want to add what is there and then + 1, I would suggest having a new field in the table for that purpose.

Comment: @simpleApp
I need to have that exact field updated instead of another one

Comment: May be strange but you can try : first update id=id+100 and then update id=id-99 so no break of constraint. You must use a number/number-1 big enough to prevent constraint to happen.

Comment: @PtitXav
Thanks!! That's a clever solution and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be strange but you can try : first update id=id+100 and then update id=id-99 so no break of constraint. You must use a number/number-1 big enough to prevent constraint to happen. – Ptit Xav 36 mins ago